# How to get the hostname of a url in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, url

I am trying to pass in a url and get just the hostname like this in react:

```
const url = "https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask";

hostname = baseurl(url);
console.log(hostname);
```

output:

```
stackoverflow
```

how would I create this function?

Comment: Check out `new URL(..)`

Answer (score 0):

There is a `URL()` function that can do this for you.

```js
let url = new URL('https://stackoverflow.com/admin');
alert(url.host);
```

Comment: this works when I directly pass in a string for for the url, but when I use a const it throws this error: TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL, even though its the exact same url, same format same everything.

Comment: It works fine for me, not sure where you're going on. If I declare a `const link = 'https://stackoverflow.com/admin'` and then do `let url = new URL(link)` followed by `console.log(url.host)`, I get the same result.